# SQL Server 2012: Copy table structure with data from one DB server to other using Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to copy table structure with data from one server to other. I already have a linked server in place in my source server. When I try to execute the below query I am getting an error.

```
SELECT Appt.C1 AS AppointmentId
    ,Appt.C2
INTO [190.28.111.187].[WH_AC].[dbo].[ApptDet]
FROM [whse].[Vw_ApptDet] Appt
INNER JOIN #DealerList DL ON DL.DealerId = Appt.DealerId
```

Error:

```
Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
The object name '190.28.111.187.WH_AC.dbo.ApptDet' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
```

I am not sure where I am missing. Please suggest me how do I perform this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on the [INTO clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx#Anchor_1):

> You cannot create new_table on a remote server; however, you can populate new_table from a remote data source. [...]

So you will have to reverse your statement (ie execute it from the remote server), or do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

> You can retrive the data using this type of code style [190.28.111.187].[WH_AC].[dbo].[ApptDet]. in case of manipulation activity the SQL do not support. I would recommend to use openrowset to achieve this concept.

```
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=YourServername;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
```

> To identify server name run the code

```
Select @@servername.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Integration Services (SSIS) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it that way (which I do next, so good question).

Just create the table first (on the remote server)

```
CREATE TABLE  dbo.[TEST](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    )
```

Then

```
insert into [server].[db].dbo.[TEST]
select * from [TEST]
```

I need to move data to a linked server where I don't sa rights next week so you had me worried. I can of course create a table but not a linked server on the remote.